# R: Print ggplots and matrices to panels in PDF?

Tags: r, pdf, matrix, ggplot2

I'm creating a multipage PDF, where each page should contain 2 graphs (ggplot2) and 2 matrices. Previously, I was using plot(), where the code and PDF layout for each page was something like this:

```
pdf("Rplots.pdf", paper = "letter", width = 7.5, height = 10)

layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,4,3,3),3,2, byrow = TRUE), heights = c(7,4,7))

# Plot at the top of each page
plot(dataTop)

# Summary at the bottom of each page
summary <- matrix(dataTop, ncol = 2, nrow = 6)
textplot(summary)

# Plot at the top of each page
plot(dataBottom)

# Summary at the bottom of each page
summary <- matrix(dataBottom, ncol = 2, nrow = 6)
textplot(summary)

dev.off()
```

I've replaced the plot() with ggplot() and have trouble getting it to print using the same panel layout.

1) Is there any simple way to print a combination of ggplots and matrices using the type of layout I have above?

2) Is there some way to ensure the ggplot is confined/expanded to some certain amount of space on the PDF?

Thank you!

Comment: I would probably use `gridExtra`, specifically its `grid.arrange` function.

Comment: It depends what you are after, but for making a report there are packages that could help. Knitr, slidify, reports, Rstudio IDE. You could make HTML slides, or PDFs and insert the image inside adding some text, description, etc.